# Tweenmax rotate is not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, gsap

I am trying to rotate two images anticlockwise using Tweenmax,in mozilla,chrome and ie9 also working.but in ie8 rotation is different.images are moving left without rotation.how to solve it.i want to support it to ie8 also.

```
<script>
 TweenMax.to(".pole1", 2, {
        top: '83px',
        left: '53px',
        rotation:-23,
        transformOrigin: "bottom center",

    });
   TweenMax.to(".pole2", 2, {
        top: '-27px',
        left: '38px',
        rotation: -40,
        transformOrigin: "bottom center",

    });

</script>
```

Comment: IE8 does not support 2D or 3D Transforms, so `transform-origin` is not supported in IE8. Only in IE9 and above. Please see - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://caniuse.com/#search=transform and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**IE8 does not support CSS3 2D or 3D Transforms**, so `transform-origin` is not supported in IE8. Only in IE9 and above.

Please see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

GreenSock GSAP TweenMax will be able to still rotate your element. GSAP works with IE propitiatory filters that deal with rotation. Such as the following:

```
/* IE6,IE7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
/* IE8 */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)";
```

You can use the following converter to get the matrix for rotation.

[IETransformsTranslator](http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/)

But GSAP can access those filters even in IE6, so you won't have to do the Math or conversion yourself, but `transform-origin` is not supported in IE8 and below.